# Commonly used test image sets

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

In the image analysis literature there are a variety of ways people show the usefulness of their method. For example, performance on an ideal signal corrupted by noise, an artificial signal encompassing a range of relevant structures, or real world images.

What are some commonly used test image sets for the following methods?

- Line and edge detection
- Corner and junction detection
- Segmentation
- Optical flow
- English / Chinese character recognition
- Handwriting author recognition
- Stereo vision / image registration

Comment: Lena and cameraman. For everything.

Answer (score 4):

**Segmentation** : [Berkeley Segmentation Dataset and Benchmark](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/)

**Stereo** : [Middlebury Stereo Datasets](http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/)

**Shape from specular flow** - [Shape from specular flow dataset](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~icvl/projects/project-sfsf.html)

Also, check out this link : http://clickdamage.com/sourcecode/cv_datasets.php

Answer (score 2):

Collections of data sets for various computer vision tasks:

- http://www.computervisiononline.com/datasets
- http://www.cvpapers.com/datasets.html